# QThread undefined reference to std function

Tags: qt, qthread

I'm trying to make static compile of my QT application. I almost've done it but there is one problem I can't resolve (I couldn't find any similar problem in google). Error looks like this:

```
path/libQt5Core.a(qthread.o):qthread.cpp:(.text$_ZN19QThreadCreateThread3runEv[_ZN19QThreadCreateThread3runEv]+0x57): undefined reference to `std::condition_variable::wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&)'
```

I've added "LIBS += -pthread" to my project file but it's still not working.
I'm working on Windows 8.1.

Comment: 1- What is the command line that you used to compile Qt framework from the source? 2- What is the compiler that is used to compile Qt and also the one that is used to compile your code? 3- Are you using the static MT or MD of Microsoft C++ library?

Comment: I've followed this article: https://tadeubento.com/2020/qt-static-builds-under-windows/. I'm using MinGW. I'm not using any Microsoft lib.

Comment: I read the tutorial you mentioned. Have you try to compile your code without these two lines: CONFIG += qt static QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++

Comment: I've tried, still the same error.